# Understanding Complicated Proverbs?

Tags: proverbs

My teacher gave us a list of 'scrambled' proverbs that we have to 'decipher' into their original meaning. Here's an example of one that our class already figured out:

"It is fruitless to become lachrymose over precipitately departed lacteal fluid." = Don't cry over spilled milk.

Our class was able to figure out most of them, but there were a few that we couldn't. The three that we didn't get were:

1. "Freedom from incrustations of grime is contiguous to rectitude"
2. "Eschew the implement of correction and vitiate the scion."
3. "Sorting on the part of mendicants must be interdicted."

Any ideas?

(The assignment won't be graded, so don't think I'm just asking for homework answers. It was just meant to be a fun Friday activity--and it was.)

Comment: Welcome to the site. While this question might be on topic you should probably include any research you did or any possibilities you ruled out. In addition, this question may be considered too broad as you technically asking three questions in one.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are.

1) "Freedom from incrustations of grime is contiguous to rectitude" 
  => Cleanliness is next to Godliness -John Wesley

2) "Eschew the implement of correction and vitiate the scion."
  => Spare the rod, spoil the child -Samuel Butler

3) "Sorting on the part of mendicants must be interdicted." 
  => Beggars cannot be choosers -Anonymous

Comment: they're fun, aren't they? if you want, i can post the rest later when i have access to a scanner.

Comment: Shouldn't 2 be "Spare the rod, spoil the child"?

Comment: Definitely fun. It was like a mini Fun Friday activity for us over here at our office, too. Definitely post the rest whenever you get the chance.

Comment: all right. i post them when i get home.

Comment: You're right on #2, McCaverty. Just edited it.